# How to test a relationship in seeds with a source() in dbt

Tags: testing, dbt

There is any way to test a seed with a relatioship coming from a external source?

I'm trying to test the seeds before creating them, to do this I'm creating in this moment a relationship test but with an external source.

I would like to do something like this in the seeds/schema.yml:

```
version: 2

seeds:
  - name: products_market
    description: ""
    columns:
      - name: id_source
        description: "ID source"
      - name: id_target
        description: "id target"
        tests:
          - relationship:
              to: source('dt', 'products')
              field: id_product
```

In this case the field id_target would be checked if exists the field id_product from dt.products

But I get the error

```
 'test_relationship' is undefined. This can happen when calling a macro that does not exist. Check for typos and/or install package dependencies with "dbt deps".
```

The sources.yml

```
version: 2

sources:
  - name: dt 
    tables:
      - name: products
        description: General Products
```

I saw this info but not sure if I'm doing it well or maybe there is another way to do this
https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/seed-properties
https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-properties/tests

Thanks in advance

Comment: post the edit as answer. I had the same issue. No docs specify this error, except this SO page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing an 's' in the test **relationships** statement in the schema.yml. Anyway it doesn't look i'm doing it properly, it says there is no test or do nothing when I do dbt seed... or dbt build

```
version: 2

seeds:
  - name: products_market
    description: ""
    columns:
      - name: id_source
        description: "ID source"
      - name: id_target
        description: "id target"
        tests:
          - relationship**s**:
              to: source('dt', 'products')
              field: id_product
```